# Is this NP optimization?

Tags: algorithm, graph, np

In a complete **n**-partite undirected graph, each partite set has **n** vertices. My problem is to find a min-weight **n**-clique in the graph. I would like to know whether the problem can be solved in poly-**n** time.

More details of the terms:

**Complete k-partite graph**: a graph in which vertices are adjacent if and only if they belong to different partite sets ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory)). There are k partite sets in the graph. In my problem, k = n.

**Clique**: A clique in a graph G is a complete subgraph of G; that is, it is a subset S of the vertices such that every two vertices in S are connected by an edge in G ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem)).

**Min-weight Clique**: Every edge in the graph has a weight. The weight of a clique is the sum of the weights of all edges in the clique. The goal is to find a clique with the minimum weight.

Note that the size of the required clique is **n**, which is the largest clique size in a complete n-partite graph, and it is always attainable.

I have searched for hours and there seems no research tackling the exact problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: We know what a clique is. Are you telling us you want to optimize an [NP hard problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) ^_^?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Well I guess it's different from the Clique Problem in the link. I hope the difference may lead to some fast solution.

Comment: There are n**k options to check in the first place ( a clique is only between edges on different parts of the graph). Just check all options checking every node in one parts (n such) against nodes in other parts, all options to choose a node from a part is n, you're doing so for k parts, so you have n^k run time (like you wanted)... that's still very slow though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I have an n-partite graph in my problem, so it should be n^n, right?

Comment: Are you making some distinction between `n-partite` and `k-partite`?  The definition seems inconsistent between the two.

Comment: @VaughnCato the k-partite graph is only used in definition.

Comment: @linusz Yes, that's still very slow, there are some [interesting optimizations](http://spectrum.library.concordia.ca/1290/1/MQ59327.pdf) that can be done though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thank you. I've browsed that paper. But it deals with the size of the clique, but in my problem, the maximum size is known to be n and I want to find a min-weight size-n clique; that's the major difference.

Comment: Are there `n` partite sets, or does each partite set contain `n` vertices, or both?

Comment: @VaughnCato both. So there are n^n such cliques :)

Comment: If I understand this correctly, there are `n^3*(n-1)/2` edges.  Is that right?

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's NP-hard via this reduction from CLIQUE.

Let (G, k) be the instance of CLIQUE (determine whether there exists a clique of cardinality at least k). Prepare a k-partite graph H with k copies of each vertex in G and edges between two vertices v and w if and only if they are in different parts and they are copies of adjacent vertices in G. There exists a k-clique in G if and only if there exists a k-clique in H. (With weights: make the existing edges weight 1 and introduce the missing ones with weight 0.)

(Surely this is in the literature, but it's Sunday, and I don't feel like looking.)

Comment: I am not sure about the reduction. My problem is to minimize the weight of the clique and the clique size is known to be the maximum, i.e., n (it's always attainable in a complete n-partite graph). Plus, in your constructed graph H, vertices that are copies of the same vertex are not connected (they are not adjacent). But it's not so in my case: any two vertices that belong to different partites are connected.

Comment: @linusz The reduction for the weighted version of the problem that interests you has a complete k-partite graph, with edges having weight 0 if they connect copies in different parts of G-adjacent vertices, and 1 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Quadratic assignment can be easily reduced to this problem by associating a location with each bipartite set and a facility with each vertex of each bipartite set.  The weight of any edge between two vertices that are associated with the same facility is set to infinity.  Since quadratic assignment is NP-hard, then this problem is NP-hard as well.